# 6510 / C64 Simulator in C++, how to realize Cycle / Clock

Tags: c++, emulation, hardware, simulation

I am trying to implement a simple C++ C64 simulator (6510 + SID and maybe VIC2).

So far we just covered the CPU basics, so I was able to implement a CPU which can read and execute instructions from memory, totally ignoring the fact that in a real C64, some instructions require more than 1 cycle.

As far as I understood:
- In Instruction-exact simulation, every instruction is executed within one CPU cycle
- In Cycle-Exact Simulation, an operation that requires 3 cycles would be split up in 3 cycles.

How important is it to do the extra effort to make the simulator cycle-exact? Can a SID and VIC even be simulated without?

Second question: Is it enough if I create a main loop, in which I call 985249 times the doCycle method of the CPU, the SID, the VIC to simulate the 0,985249MHz?

EDIT: 
Not quite sure if I understood it correctly:

```
void CPU::emulateCPUCycle(){
    cyclesLeft--;

    if (cyclesLeft<= 0){

        // fetch op-code
        uint8_t op = mem->read_byte(reg_pc);

        executeInstruction(op);

        cyclesLeft= numOfCyclesTable[op]; // contains the required cycle number per instruction

        // increase PC
        reg_pc++;

    }
    else
      // waste cycle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"How important is it to do the extra effort to make the simulator cycle-exact? Can a SID and VIC even be simulated without?"

Main question is why you are doing this. If your aim is to be able to somehow run original c64 games then probably you will need to be timing precise as many old games depend on precise timing of things. HOWEVER, even if you write a cycle exact emulator the chances of getting that degree of precision on a modern non real-time OS (linux, windows,..) to actually work are low.

Just write an emulator that does the right thing and ignores timing. Thats a hard enough problem in its own right

Comment: Thank you, my goal is just to create a working simulator, if it will show anything, I will be already more than happy.

Answer (score 0):

the datasheet/documentation tells you how many clocks for each of the instructions as you simu/emulate the instruction you keep count of clocks.  you need/use this for example to have periodic interrupts.  I dont know the c64 that well but if for example there is some time based interrupt you convert that to clocks, if accumulated clocks > N then you interrupt and subtract N from that counter.

generally some processors have different execution times depending on variations on the instruction.  a memory version vs a register version may have an extra clock or to for example.

I doubt seriously these were pipelined so I doubt seriously there is anything parallel to worry about, just accumulate the clocks based on the chip docs per instruction.

EDIT:

Not sure what you are trying to do there.  that isnt what I was talking about.  Normally on those systems you would have some timer driven events, for example you would update the display based on either the display refreshes (h or v) or some time based interrupt that comes along so many milliseconds.   For a c64 I assume the keyboard was handled by separate logic then you were given a code of some sort, but say a handheld or arcade machine the main cpu might need to sample the inputs on some interval as well (and maybe deal with bounce but that is another topic that the interrupt might cover for you).  so it is okay if you get there ahead of the interrupt.  in a real time system like a game for example you need the next screen ready before the next screen refresh, every refresh.  so what if you get there way early you just spin and wait for the refresh.  So you dont need to have every cpu instruction delayed as if you were back running a few megahertz.  start with just these user interface events, and see how that works.

you dont normally want a down counter unless you handle negative numbers, makes it more accurate to roll the fraction into the next time period.  if say it is 250 cpu cycles per interrupt, and you interrupt on 252 because the last instruction was 3 clocks.  save the extra 2 for the next time period.  subtract 250, 2 are left on the variable that accumulates clocks for that interrupt.

just go look at the m6502 or other instruction set simulators out there used to do this kind of thing, there are tons of them.  mame is loaded with them although that code is tuned for performance back from the 386 days, we dont need to over-optimize the code like that anymore, but it is what it is.

from a static binary translator I wrote for the 6502

```
case 0xA1:
    printf("case 0x%04X: //%02X %02X %02X\n",opadd,opcode,rom[opadd+1],rom[opadd+2]);
    printf("    clockticks+=6;\n");
    temp=rom[opadd+1];
    printf("    value=0x%02X; value+=X;\n",temp); //this should clip
    printf("    temp=ReadMemory(value+1);\n");
    printf("    temp<<=8;\n");
    printf("    temp|=ReadMemory(value);\n");
    printf("    A=ReadMemory(temp);\n");
    printf("  ZN=A;\n");
    break;
```

then elsewhere

```
    if(ticks>250)
    {
        ticks-=250;
        rom[0x2001] ^= 0xff;
        if (++nmi_count >= 24)
        {
              nmi_count = 0;
printf("INT\n");
              return(INT_NMI);
        }
    }
```

this was asteroids I later figured out how the specific rom worked and where the code was that waited for the interrupt to have happened to allow the code to advance to the next frame.  the interrupt was also used to sample the coin slot which I didnt care to emulate, etc...so I was able to remove the interrupt completely.

But if you are making a generic system emulator then you cant take those shortcuts.  You can if you want average out each instruction and just call it 3 clocks or whatever rather than trying to get too accurate.

in this case if the branch happens then we add an additional clock

```
case 0xF0:
    printf("case 0x%04X: //%02X %02X %02X\n",opadd,opcode,rom[opadd+1],rom[opadd+2]);
    printf("    clockticks+=2;\n");
    temp=rom[opadd+1];
    if(temp&0x80) temp-=0x100;
    temp2=(opadd+temp+2)&addrmask;
    printf("    if(ZN==0)//if zero\n");
    printf("    { \n");
    printf("        clockticks++;  \n");
    printf("        //showme(0x%04X,0x%02X);\n",opadd,opcode);
    printf("        PCSTART=0x%04X;\n",temp2);
    printf("        /**/return;\n");
    printf("        //goto L_%04X;\n",temp2);
    printf("    } \n");
    break;
```

and if you are not that interested in accuracy and use an average clock time to save coding or code space, then you probably dont care about the extra clocks at an interrupt period 252 is good enough vs 250 to toss the two extra.  I still think an up counter is easier, but thats just me...

Comment: Thank you, I'm still not quite sure if I understood it correctly. I updated my Question. Mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

First I believe there are already enough c64 emulators/simulators which are working well. https://www.c64-wiki.de/index.php/VICE ( german website ). Maybe you find the link list helpful: https://www.c64-wiki.de/index.php/Portal:Emulatoren ( also german, but following the links should be possible without knowing german well ;) )

As next you can start from scratch if your intention is to learn programming. It is a good practice doing this. If you want fast results, you can have a look in other open source simulators like one for a 8 bit cpu like avr here: http://www.nongnu.org/simulavr/. This simulator is cycle accurate. The intention for simulavr was measuring interrupt latency as well as all other execution time measurement. It also allows connection to other hardware like flashes, LCD, uarts and a lot of other stuff. You also can simulate multiple cores there which are all running with different clock speed/cycle time. And also additional interrupt cycles ( fetching irq vector ) are also simulated. And in addition, the behavior of the instruction pipeline is simulated, because a read / write action on a prot register will seen not within the next cycle cause of the pipelining of the core. So it is a simple startpoint for small cpu cores.

And for your question:

> How important is it to do the extra effort to make the simulator cycle-exact? Can a SID and VIC even be simulated without?

It is absolutely important to simulate as precise as possible. The c64 software was often handcrafted assembler stuff to get correct timings for a lot of wild things to run. This starts from bit banging for the protocols on the extension ports or software uarts. And also a lot of things like shadow ram behind the screen buffer is absolutely important for that computer.

But indeed, all the work has already done I believe and can be found on the net... So it is a question what you want to achieve? Learning by making or using it.